# Show that the field of fractions of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(i)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Let $\mathbb{Z}[i] = \{a+bi : a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(i) = \{a+bi : a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$.
>
> Show that the field of fractions of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is isomorphic to
>   $\mathbb{Q}(i)$.

Define $Q = \{rd^{-1}=(r_1 + i r_2 )(d_1 + i d_2)^{-1} : r \in \mathbb{Z}[i] , d \in \mathbb{Z}[i] - \{0\}\} $ as the field of fraction of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

I think I could use the fonction $\phi : Q \to \mathbb{Q}(i)$ such that $\phi(rd^{-1}) = \frac{r_1}{d_1} + i\frac{r_2}{d_2}$.

Is there a clever and shorter way I can prove this question?

Comment: Your idea won't work, essentially since $\frac{r_1+ir_2}{d_1+id_2}\neq\frac{r_1}{d_1}+i\frac{r_2}{d_2}$.

Comment: @EricWofsey Could I replace $ \frac{r_1}{d_1}+i\frac{r_2}{d_2}$ by  $\frac{r_1+ir_2}{d_1+id_2}$?

Comment: It seems to me the central idea of the argument would be the usual technique for dividing complex numbers by multiplying the numerator and denominator by the complex conjugate of the denominator. $\qquad$

Answer (score 3):

Let $K$ be the fraction field of $\Bbb Z[i]$. From the inclusion, $\Bbb Z[i] \subset \Bbb Q[i]$ and the fact that $\Bbb Q[i]$ is a field, we know that $K \subset \Bbb Q[i]$. Moreover, from the inclusion $\Bbb Z \subset \Bbb Z[i]$, we know that $\Bbb Q \subset K$. So we have $$\Bbb Q \subset K \subset \Bbb Q[i].$$ Now all these guys are $\Bbb Q$-vector spaces. By a simple dimension argument, can you show that $K=\Bbb Q[i]$?

Comment: Scuse me, but I have never done linear algebra. Could you tell me more? I do math since 4 years now, and I have 13 years old today.

Comment: Ok, I strongly encourage you to learn some linear algebra before you start doing abstract algebra and especially field theory. That being said, have you seen the notion of field extensions? If yes then $\Bbb Q \subset K \subset \Bbb Q[i]$ are field extensions and $[\Bbb Q : \Bbb Q[i]]=2$, so you can also conclude from here.

Comment: No, I don't see field extensions. Do I have to use the initial method I use in the question?

Comment: Ok, then I think Micheal Hardy's comment gives you the easiest way to do this exercise without using "heavy" machinery.